# closures not working in firefox sdk

Tags: javascript, closures, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to create a button list with automatically assigned onclick events.

```
document.getElementById('buttonList').innerHTML = '';
for(var $c = 0; $c < $buttons.length; $c++) {
    document.getElementById('buttonList').innerHTML += '<li><button id="button-' + $c + '">' + $buttons[$c].text + '</button></li>';
    document.querySelector('#button-' + $c).onclick = (function($index) {
        return function() {
            console.log($index);
        };
    })($c);
}
```

In my opinion, if i click a button it should log 0/1/2/3/... But none of the buttons is working, except the last one. The last button returns the right index.

So my question, what is wrong?

Comment: $button = [
{'text': 'Button #1'},
{'text': 'Button #2'},
{'text': 'Button #3'}
]

Comment: `$button` or `$buttons`, you are using `$buttons` for the loop.

Comment: sry, ments $buttons = [ {'text': 'Button #1'}, {'text': 'Button #2'}, {'text': 'Button #3'} ];
 But as i said, the loop is working fine, but doesn't bind the onclick event to the buttons except the last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `innerHTML += ...`, it destroys the older `onclick` handlers. You can fix this in one of two ways:

- Use `appendChild` instead of `innerHTML += ...`:

  ```
  document.getElementById('buttonList').innerHTML = '';
  for(var $c = 0; $c < $buttons.length; $c++) {
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      var button = document.createElement('button');
      button.setAttribute('id', 'button-' + $c);
      button.innerHTML = $buttons[$c].text;
      button.onclick = (function($index) {
          return function() {
              console.log($index);
          };
      })($c);
      li.appendChild(button);
      document.getElementById('buttonList').appendChild(li);
  }
  ```
- Generate the HTML first, then add the event handlers all at once:

  ```
  document.getElementById('buttonList').innerHTML = '';
  for(var $c = 0; $c < $buttons.length; $c++) {
      document.getElementById('buttonList').innerHTML += '<li><button id="button-' + $c + '">' + $buttons[$c].text + '</button></li>';
  }

  for(var $c = 0; $c < $buttons.length; $c++) {
      document.querySelector('#button-' + $c).onclick = (function($index) {
          return function() {
              console.log($index);
          };
      })($c);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

When you modify the `innerHTML` property, the element gets rerendered, so the elements, that you've bind the `onclick` to, do not exist in the DOM anymore (except the last one).

From [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML):

> Removes all of element's children, parses the content string and assigns the resulting nodes as children of the element.

If you still want to use `innerHTML`, the solution is to create a container element (`<li>`), append it to your list and then modify its `innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById('buttonList').innerHTML = '';
for (var $c = 0; $c < $buttons.length; $c++) {
    var liItem = document.createElement("li");
    document.getElementById('buttonList').appendChild(liItem);
    liItem.innerHTML = '<button id="button-' + $c + '">' + $buttons[$c].text + '</button>';
    console.log(document.querySelector('#button-' + $c));
    document.querySelector('#button-' + $c).onclick = (function ($index) {
        return function () {
            console.log($index);
        };
    })($c);
}
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ThNv3/)